# Detecting the closest edge to a point in 3D space

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm trying to develop an efficient way for detecting the closest edge (of a polygon mesh) to a point in 3D space without iterating over each edge. Does anyone know of any existing algorithms that do this?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Val

Comment: If by edge you mean the edge of a graph then breadth-first search finds the shortest path to all the nodes reachable from a vertex. If you're in a single-source problem then Djikstra's algorithm could also do it.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. I meant like a polygon edge

Comment: Is the polygon mesh convex?

Answer (score 0):

An approximative solution would be to generate number of points from each edge, create a spatial structure (kd-tree for example) with the resulting points, and use that for nn-search.

However, this approach is only worthwhile if approximate solution is acceptable for you and if you are going to perform many nn queries.